# What is the best way to maintain API change-logs using API Blueprint?

Tags: api, apiblueprint

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to maintain and communicate change-log to api consumer using api-blueprint? Preferably I don't want to use another 3rd party service like [apichangelog](http://www.apichangelog.com) to communicate the changes.

Answer (score -1):

We (Apiary) do not offer any tool which can help you doing that at the moment.

If you're using any kind of hosted source control system (GitHub, Bitbucket), you could throw a webhook whenever a change reaches the master branch, which usually means something like *I introduced a change in my API*.

Once that happens, in your webhook handler you could have a look to all your issued API Keys, reach the provided support email and send a notification there.